# How do I use %localappdata% inside a system() call?

Tags: c++, winapi, terminal

Let's say I want to make a program that opens `%localappdata%`. I would do `system("start %localappdata%");` But it doesn’t work.

I need this program to open `%localappdata%` with a menu selection (I already made the menu selection).

Comment: What IDE are you using? What compiler are you using? The `%localappdata%` *looks* like some sort of macro such as used by MSVC/Visual Studio, but we need details and clarity. Also, can you confirm that you are targeting Windows?

Comment: [`system()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) doesn't expand environment variables for you. You'll have to do that manually.

Comment: There's actually a fairly straightforward way to this using the WinAPI. Clarify and tidy-up your question and it may be reopened so that someone can post the answer.

Comment: You can't use environment variables in a `system()` call. You will have to store your wanted command in a `char[]` buffer and call `ExpandEnvironmentStringsA()` on it first, then pass it to `system()`.  Otherwise, don't use environment variables at all, use [`SHGetFolderPathA(CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha) or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath), and then build up your command string from that.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in the comments, you can't just use the `%localappdata%` macro in a string you pass to the `system()` function. Furthermore, you also can't just paste environment variables like that into C++ code and expect the compiler to resolve them, as they aren't *actually* defined as compiler macros.

Instead, you can call a WinAPI routine to get the value for the "Local App Data" folder, then write that into the string you pass to the `system()` call. Here's the 'modern' (post Windows-Vista) way to do this:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    wchar_t* wpath; // Recieves the address of a system-allocated Unicode string
    SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, nullptr, &wpath);
    std::wcout << wpath << L"\n";
    wchar_t wcommand[_MAX_PATH + 10];
    // Note, in the below format, the escaped double quotes around the path!
    swprintf(wcommand, L"start \"%s\"", wpath);
    _wsystem(wcommand);
    CoTaskMemFree(wpath); // It is your responsinility to free that string!
    return 0;
}
```

If, for some reason, you want to use a plain, single-byte character string for the path, then you can use the 'older' `SHGetFolderPath()` API call, as shown below. But note that [Microsoft recommends using the newer method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha).

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char path[_MAX_PATH];
    SHGetFolderPath(nullptr, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, nullptr, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, path);
    std::cout << path << "\n";
    char command[_MAX_PATH + 10];
    sprintf(command, "start \"%s\"", path);
    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: `%LOCALAPPDATA%` is not the same as `$(LOCALAPPDATA)` -- yes, the latter is a Visual Studio macro, but the former is just an environment variable. Open `cmd.exe` and type `SET L`, and you'll see `LOCALAPPDATA` defined there.

Comment: @heapunderrun Well-spotted! I have edited that part out of the answer.

Comment: Strangely, it worked without any particular things.